# vuejs scoped styles not working with d3js

Tags: d3.js, vue.js

I am trying to integrate Vue.js and D3.js. What I notice is sometimes the CSS classes don't really work on the svg elements. I am giving the snippet of the vue component below.

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <svg width="300" height="100" ref="barchart"></svg>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default {
  name: "LineChart",
  mounted() {
    d3.select("h1").attr("class","red-text")
    var data = [10,20,15,30,60];
    var barHeight = 20;
    var bar = d3
      .select(this.$refs.barchart)
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class","rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")";
      });
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.rect{
    fill: blue;
}
.red-text{
  color:red;
}
</style>
```

Its output is obtained as :-

[scoped css output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCA2Q.png)

But as sson as I remove the scoped attribute, the code works fine. New output :-

[global css output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63f7R.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe specifying vue's deep child selector would work? e.g. `svg >>> .rect { ... }` .

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino it's working! But is this considered a good practice?

Comment: Your svg selector still gets scoped, so the styles shouldn't leak outside the component. I don't see any drawbacks for this.

Answer (score 8):

Scoped styles work by vue assigning a unique attribute to dom elements, and then adjusting the style rules by adding an extra criteria for elements to have that attribute. [Example in vue guide](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#scoped-css). However, since elements dynamically created with d3 aren't managed by vue (since they aren't part of the template), it doesn't work out of the box. One way to solve this, is to to use deep selector (e.g. `svg >>> .rect { ... }`), which doesn't attach the additional unique attribute criteria for the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to color the bars you don't need explicit css. You can just set:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return 'blue'; })
```

on your bar.

Comment: Don't need a function for a constant

Comment: True, just left it there so that one can see that it does not need to be the same color for every bar.